# Deduplicating and merging dataframe with node polar js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have tried to clean the CSV file, to remove the duplicates and insert the fields from the columns where the data is missing.

All that is done, but when I try to drop the duplicates in the end with function to drop duplicates of the same key, the values in another columns got messed up. Basically inside those columns I have text has commas in it and when it tries to drop the duplicates, it destroys the text where the comma is.

Is there a way to handle this?

`df = df.unique({ maintainOrder: true, subset: ['base'], keep: 'first' })`

After running this I lose the stuff from the columns

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.